# Google Cloud Platform: Is there a way to get information about the creator of a service account, using the service account key

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I need to find the email of the GCP user, that created a given service account, using only that service account's json key as authentication in Python.

I tried using the Logging API, but the results don't always contain the log about the creation of the service account.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud records the IAM identity that created a service account in the Audit Log. Audit logs are retained for 400 days. Provided that the service account has permission to read the log and the entry is still in the logs, you can determine the identity that created the service account.

[Cloud Audit Logs overview](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit)

This is an example log entry for creating a service account. The `protoPayload.authenticationInfo` key contains the identity that created the service account.

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "hao@example.com"
    },
    "methodName": "google.iam.admin.v1.CreateServiceAccount",
    "response": {
      "email": "my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.iam.admin.v1.ServiceAccount",
      "display_name": "My service account."
    }
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "service_account"
  }
}
```